# global obsensor_uvc_stream_channel.cpp:156 getStreamChannelGroup Camera index out of range

Tags: python, opencv, runtime-error

I have deployed a face recognition based attendance system on render.com. It was deployed successfully but when I try to access the webcam of local computer I get error and the log for the same is attached below. But the same program when ran on local machine runs successfully. It only gives a warning message saying:

```
DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
if extract_faces(frame) != ():
```

Please can someone help me with this problem?

```
Feb 4 05:52:43 PM  [ WARN:0@22.018] global cap_v4l.cpp:982 open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index
Feb 4 05:52:43 PM  [ERROR:0@22.018] global obsensor_uvc_stream_channel.cpp:156 getStreamChannelGroup Camera index out of range
Feb 4 05:52:43 PM  ERROR:app:Exception on /start [GET]
Feb 4 05:52:43 PM  Traceback (most recent call last):
Feb 4 05:52:43 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
Feb 4 05:52:43 PM      response = self.full_dispatch_request()
Feb 4 05:52:43 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
Feb 4 05:52:43 PM      rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
Feb 4 05:52:43 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
Feb 4 05:52:43 PM      rv = self.dispatch_request()
Feb 4 05:52:43 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
Feb 4 05:52:43 PM      return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
Feb 4 05:52:43 PM    File "app.py", line 117, in start
Feb 4 05:52:43 PM      if extract_faces(frame) != ():
Feb 4 05:52:43 PM    File "app.py", line 42, in extract_faces
Feb 4 05:52:43 PM      gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
Feb 4 05:52:43 PM  cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'
```

The function which raises this error is:

```
@app.route('/start', methods=['GET'])
def start():
    if 'face_recognition_model.pkl' not in os.listdir('static'):
        return render_template('home.html', totalreg=totalreg(), datetoday2=datetoday2(),
                           mess='There is no trained model in the static folder. Please add a new face to continue.')

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    #cap = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)
    ret = True
    while ret:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if extract_faces(frame) != ():
            (x, y, w, h) = extract_faces(frame)[0]
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 20), 2)
            face = cv2.resize(frame[y:y + h, x:x + w], (50, 50))
            identified_person = identify_face(face.reshape(1, -1))[0]
            add_attendance(identified_person)
            cv2.putText(frame, f'{identified_person}', (30, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1,     (255, 0, 20), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.imshow('Attendance', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
            break
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    userDetails = extract_attendance()
    return render_template('home.html', l=len(userDetails), totalreg=totalreg(),
                       datetoday2=datetoday2(), userDetails=userDetails)
```

I tried to change the index number of webcam but it raised same error. I want to understand how do I access my local webcam by the server.

Comment: why _should_ a random server on the internet have a webcam attached to it? do you want this server to access a webcam on your local computer? how is it supposed to do that? how did you debug this issue? did you run your code in the python debugger, while on the server? have you checked that VideoCapture could be opened, with `isOpened()` after creation? you don't have the "informed" badge yet, so please take the [tour] and review [ask]

Comment: Why did you put `cv2.imshow()` outside `if/else` block and you put `if cv2.waitKey()` inside `if/else` condition block?

Put this outside of `if/else` block.

    cv2.imshow('Attendance', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break